# What do I need to get rid of Permission denied error on Linux?

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, tomcat

I have tomcat installed in /opt/tomcat and would like to get access to sub-folders for user 'mck'.

```
mck@hp15-pc:/opt/tomcat$ ls bin
ls: cannot open directory 'bin': Permission denied

mck@hp15-pc:/opt/tomcat$
```

here are the permissions for /opt/tomcat

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 tomcat tomcat 4.0K 2020-12-23 21:30:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root   4.0K 2020-12-23 21:25:41 ../
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat tomcat 4.0K 2020-12-23 21:29:32 bin/
drwx------ 3 tomcat tomcat 4.0K 2020-12-23 21:43:09 conf/
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat tomcat 4.0K 2020-12-23 21:29:32 lib/
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat tomcat 4.0K 2020-12-23 21:35:40 logs/
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat tomcat 4.0K 2020-12-23 21:50:10 temp/
drwxr-x--- 7 tomcat tomcat 4.0K 2020-12-03 06:45:57 webapps/
drwxr-x--- 3 tomcat tomcat 4.0K 2020-12-23 21:35:40 work/
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat  19K 2020-12-03 06:48:29 BUILDING.txt
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat 5.3K 2020-12-03 06:48:29 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat  56K 2020-12-03 06:48:29 LICENSE
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat 2.3K 2020-12-03 06:48:29 NOTICE
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat 3.2K 2020-12-03 06:48:29 README.md
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat 6.8K 2020-12-03 06:48:29 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r----- 1 tomcat tomcat  17K 2020-12-03 06:48:30 RUNNING.txt
```

I have added 'mck' user to 'tomcat' group here are the groups for 'mck'

```
mck@hp15-pc:/opt/tomcat$ groups mck
mck : mck tomcat
```

I noticed this strange output of 'id', I do not see the group 'tomcat' in the groups list if I omit the username.

```
mck@hp15-pc:~$ id
uid=1000(mck) gid=1000(mck) groups=1000(mck),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),114(lpadmin),134(sambashare)

mck@hp15-pc:~$ id mck
uid=1000(mck) gid=1000(mck) groups=1000(mck),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),114(lpadmin),134(sambashare),1002(tomcat)
```

I do not want to change the permissions or user and groups on the tomcat folder '/opt/tomcat'.

What do I need to do to allow access to sub-folders of /opt/tomcat for user 'mck'? Is it possible?

I logged out and logged in again but the problem is not resolved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot add user to group properly on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/931843/cannot-add-user-to-group-properly-on-linux)

Comment: Additional info: [Why is the output from `groups` different from `groups user` if Im currently logged in as user?](https://superuser.com/q/294650/432690) and maybe [Reload a Linux user's group assignments without logging out](https://superuser.com/q/272061/432690).

Comment: I logged out and re-login but the issue did not go away.

Comment: Are `id` and `id mck` still showing different output?

Comment: How exactly did you go about creating this group and adding your user to it?

Answer (score 0):

I first tried logout and re-login but it did not resolve the issue.

I had to restart the system for the issue to go away.

Also, now the "id" and "id mck" both show identical output.